# Extract Next Row for Next Loop in iMacros

Tags: firefox, imacros

This is my first post on Stack Overflow. I am looking for someone to help me find solution.

Details:

1. Go to http://sslproxies.org/
2. Type "un" in search box
3. Extract 1st IP address and port
4. Run next command

**Please note. My script is working properly**. But, how to choose 2nd row for 2nd loop, 3rd row for 3rd loop, etc until 5th loop. After 5th loop, repeat process (6th loop choose 1st row again).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better if you provided a minimal working example of the relevant html and javascript and add it as a snippet to stackoverflow as pages will go offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope my answer is much closer to the context of your issue:

```
SET step 5
SET pos EVAL({{!LOOP}}%{{step}}?{{!LOOP}}%{{step}}:{{step}})
TAG XPATH="//tbody/tr[{{pos}}]/td[1]" EXTRACT=TXT
TAG XPATH="//tbody/tr[{{pos}}]/td[2]" EXTRACT=TXT
```